# WP8 - Binding commands to buttons and switches in list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, data-binding, windows-phone

I am using MVVM pattern and I have LongListSelector in my page but I am not sure how to do these bindings:

- I want in each row a button which do something with object in that row. I have this prepare in ViewModel:

  ```
  private RelayCommand<Module> goToTrackingPageCommand;

  public RelayCommand<Module> GoToTrackingPageCommand
  {
      get
      {
          return goToTrackingPageCommand
              ?? (goToTrackingPageCommand = new RelayCommand<Module>(
                   NavigateToTrackingPage));
      }
  }

  private void NavigateToTrackingPage(Module module)
  {
      App.Current.SelectedModule = module;
      navigationService.NavigateTo(new Uri("/Views/ModuleTrackingPage.xaml"), UriKind.Relative);
  }
  ```

  And I am trying to bind it like this:

  ```
  <Button x:Name="ShowButton" Content="Show" 
                          Command="{Binding GoToTrackingPageCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
  ```

  It's not working because button is in datatemplate and when there is binding it goes to selected Module object but not to ViewModel. So my first question is how can I fix it?
- Second one is little complicated I guess but hope both get easy solution. I want have in each row ToggleSwitch too and when value is changed I want to call http request. I have this in datatemplate:

  ```
  <toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="LockSwitch" IsChecked="{Binding IsLock}" />
  ```

  I could change binding to TwoWay but I change value in object and I want to call method in ViewModel with Module argument. So have can I change this binding? Should I someway call method in ViewModel from my object? Or should I somehow tell ViewModel that this object has changed this value? Or should I bind Checked and Unchecked event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the Buttons:
You can access the "parent datacontext" with an elementName binding and set the command parameter:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.GoToXyCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

Regarding your second question:

First, I would check if a toggle-button is the right solution, if changing the value triggers a process with a possibly longer duration.

An example where WP does this is enabling/disabling Air-Plane Mode.

I would do it the same way:

- Bind to the property via TwoWayBinding
- When the property is changed, start the updating process, disable the toggle button and show a progress indicator.

EDIT: Here is and example from a ViewModel I recently used.

```
    public bool IsUpdatingPushEnabled
    {
        get { return _isUpdatingPushEnabled; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _isUpdatingPushEnabled, value); }
    }

    public bool IsPushEnabled
    {
        get { return _isPushEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (!IsUpdatingPushEnabled)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _isPushEnabled, value);
                var t = SetPushAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task SetPushAsync()
    {
        IsUpdatingPushEnabled = true;

        try
        {
            var result = await _settingService.EnablePushAsync(IsPushEnabled);
            SetProperty(ref _isPushEnabled, result, "IsPushEnabled");
        }
        catch
        {
            //...
        }

        IsUpdatingPushEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know about accessing parent. It looks like right way. For second question: How would you start updating process from setter? How would you call method in ViewModel? Thanks to IoC I have ApiService class (for managing api calls) in ViewModel and how to access it?

Comment: I (personal opinion) would just trigger some "OnXyChanged" method from within the property setter.

Comment: Looks good but one more thing. When I some method in VM (with parent datacontext) how can I set it was this object from list? In button it is easy with command parameter but how can I do this with ToggleSwitch?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. With your button, you only have to provide the Datacontext as CommandParameter, because your button was inside if a list control (the lists set the datacontext of each item to the list source item). As the toggle-button binds to a specific property, it doesn't need to give more context.